# browser keeps opening new tabs/windows by itself on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, firefox

Google Chrome keeps opening new tabs / windows by itself until it uses all the processor and RAM then I have to restart.
I thought it was a bug with Chrome so I Switched to Firefox and the problem remains the same.
How do I stop this from happening?
I am using Linux xububtu version 18.4 LTS

Comment: Maybe it's the problem with your keyboard? Maybe you spilled something on your laptop.

Comment: I had a very similar problem, but it was opening up unlimited calculator apps.  In my case, the little calculator key on my Microsoft keyboard was sticky.  Maybe you have a key that maps to opening a tab or window.  I turned my keyboard upside down and shook it while I blew on the key to solve it.

Comment: I will change the keyboard and see if that fixes the problem. but I doubt it.